# Express middleware: allow access to only admin or moderator

Tags: node.js, express

I want a route to be only accessible by moderator or admin.
I tried to apply a middleware of array on the route. But, it just denies access if one middleware fails to apply.
so, say I am admin or moderator  I can access to `/store-detail`.
But here, If I am admin I can not access it because it check for moderator as well.
 
Here *both middlewares `admin` and `moderator` is being applied.*
I want it to  apply `admin` or `moderator`.
How can I make just one of them to be applied?

So that only admin or moderator can access it.

*`verify` middleware is to verify jwt token.* 
**router**

```
router.post('/store-detail', [verify, admin, moderator], async (req, res) => {
    //validate data
}}
```

**middlewares**

```
const User = require('../models').User

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) { 
    // 401 Unauthorized
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id : req.user.id}})
    if(user.role !== 'moderator') return res.status(403).send({error: { status:403, message:'Access denied.'}});
    next();
  }
```

```
const User = require('../models').User

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) { 
    // 401 Unauthorized
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id : req.user.id}})
    if(user.role !== 'admin') return res.status(403).send({error: { status:403, message:'Access denied.'}});
    next();
  }
```

Comment: Frankly, speaking is slightly hard to comprehend your question. Can you please try to be more detailed and ease up the language?

Comment: also, making a network request in middleware just doesn't seem to be an idle approach. Results in unnecessary calls to db which causes performance issue .

Comment: @iRohitBhatia I updated the description.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari create a new middleware that will check either the user is moderator or admin instead of applying both middlewares

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Middlewares are executed successively, so the first middleware that denies access, sends an error.
I suggest to create a single middleware that accepts a parameter:

```js
module.exports = function hasRole(roles) {
  return async function(req, res, next) {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: req.user.id } });
    if (!user || !roles.includes(user.role)) {
      return res.status(403).send({error: { status:403, message:'Access denied.'}});
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

And use the middleware like this:

```js
router.post('/store-detail', verify, hasRole(['admin', 'moderator']), async (req, res) => {})
```

Comment: This is nice, I adopted my jwt based answer to use this generic role checking.

Comment: instead of naming it `hasRole`, `authorize` seems good to me, also I will encrypt role into the jwt, so no extra db call.

Comment: @Jérémie There is missing `)` in if condition.

Answer (score 2):

Here I explain json web token based solution:

users route (routes/users.js)
Here I return a auth-token in login operation.

```js
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const hasRole = require("../middleware/hasRole");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const { User } = require("../models/user");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  let user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

  user = new User({ name, email, password });
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  await user.save();

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
  res.header("auth-token", token).send({ name, email });
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  let user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");

  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();

  res.send(token);
});

module.exports = router;
```

user.js (User Model)
Here I add role information to the jwt when signing it:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: "user"
  }
});

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { _id: this._id, role: this.role },
    process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY
  );
  return token;
};

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

exports.User = User;
```

middleware/auth.js
Here I authenticate the user, and adding decoded token to the request so that we can use in the next middlewares.

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("auth-token");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied. No token provided.");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY);
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid token.");
  }
};
```

middleware/hasRole.js
Here we check if the user.role satisfies the required roles.

```js
module.exports = function hasRole(roles) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user.role || !roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return res.status(403).send("Access denied.");
    }

    next();
  };
};
```

Lastly we add the following path to the users route to be able to test role authorization.

```js
router.get("/me", [auth, hasRole(["admin", "moderator"])], async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select("-password");
  res.send(user);
});
```

To test:

Create 3 users separately with following with POST to the following url

http://localhost:3000/api/users/register

```
{
    "name": "admin",
    "email": "admin@so.com",
    "password" : "123456"
}

{
    "name": "moderator",
    "email": "moderator@so.com",
    "password" : "123456"
}

{
    "name": "user",
    "email": "user@so.com",
    "password" : "123456"
}
```

In mongodb,  in the users collection we update role property  to admin  for admin user, and moderator  for moderator user.

Using postman or similar tool we Login with admin or moderator credentials.

In the response, we get the auth token, we use it in auth-token header for this protected endpoint in GET request.

http://localhost:3000/api/users/me

You will get status code 200.

This time we login with normal user credentials.
In the response, we copy the auth token, and use it in auth-token header  for this protected endpoint in GET request.

http://localhost:3000/api/users/me

You will get status code 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I agree for you add role property in the jwt. But I don't think this a good solution for me because. I will have so many middleware for different access control in this case. like yours adminOrModerator for admin or moderator

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari I updated answer for generic role checking.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new function e.g. `isAuthorized` to handle that logic.

If you call `[verify, admin, moderator]` separately they are not depended on each other.

route:

```
router.post('/store-detail', isAuthorized, async (req, res) => {
    //validate data
}}

function isAuthorized(req, res, next) {
  if (!verify(req)) 
    return next();
  if (!admin(req) && !moderator(req)) 
    return res.status(403).send({error: { status:403, message:'Access denied.'}});
}
```

middleware:

```
const User = require('../models').User

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) { 
  // 401 Unauthorized
  const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id : req.user.id}})
  if(user.role === 'moderator') 
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

I think you have to modify `verify(req)`, `admin(req)` and `moderator(req)`.

Comment: How can `isAuthorized()` function access `req, res, and next` when you define it?

Answer (score 1):

**Irrelevant part**

From system architecture point of view, here is what I will do.

1. Instead of making network request inside the middleware everytime, store the user access level in a token (say jwt token).
2. The moment user login to the system, make a request to the backend, the backend will make request to db to retrive the details (which should consider access level) and encrypt the user details in token. Your token should contain the access level.
3. On every request, You will have token in the headers, de-crypt the token, and set the details of access levels (res.locals should be the ideal place to set tokens).

```
   const verifyUser = async (req, res, next) => {
        const token = req.cookies.userId
        if(token) {
          try {
            const tokenVerficiation = await verifyToken(token)
            res.locals.userId = tokenVerficiation.userId
            next()
          } catch (error) {
            return res.status(401).send(`Invalid Access token`)
          }
        } else { 
         return res.status(401).send(`Not Authorized to view this.`)
        }
    }
```

**Relevant part**

Since you are setting `res.status(403).send({error: { status:403, message:'Access denied.'}});` it makes sense why it won't move to the next middleware.

Since for an APi call you can `*Probably` send headers once
As suggested by **Jérémie L** creating a single-new middleware would be the best approach

```
module.exports = function hasRole(roles) {
  return async function(req, res, next) {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: req.user.id } });
    if (!user || !roles.includes(user.role) {
      return res.status(403).send({error: { status:403, message:'Access denied.'}});
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree I encrypted role into the jwt while generating it.